# Where are OData/ADF Access Tokens stored?

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, odata, ambient-data-framework

We have two serves running an OData CD Web Service behind a load balancer (each pointing at the same clustered Broker DB). Our web apps are configured to get an Access Token before making requests to the actual service.

So what I want to understand is... do I need to make sure that the Web App requests the Access Token and the Data from the same server, or is the Token stored in the Broker DB so that it can be shared between both Odata Web Services

Answer (score 3):

The data can be shared across machine using following:

In the cd_storage_conf.xml, in session wrappers give the same machine name across all the servers that are sharing the access token.

Given below is the sample sessionwrapper. Here, you can replace xyz with some meaningful machine name and then data from all the servers will be stored in session broker database with that machine name.

```
<Wrappers>
            <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
                <Timeout>120000</Timeout>
                <MachineName>xyz</MachineName>
                <Storage Type="persistence" Id="db-session-webservice" 

dialect="MSSQL"Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory"> 
... 
</Storage>

</Wrapper>          
</Wrappers>
```

Reference: [Tridion documentation for load balancing](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-3B6CF732-24B7-4281-82E1-7B9FB6D44896&addHistory=true&query=wrapper&scope=&tid=fc72a79c-d2ee-4c1d-a129-d8104cdee136&filename=GUID-3B6CF732-24B7-4281-82E1-7B9FB6D44896.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3B6CF732-24B7-4281-82E1-7B9FB6D44896&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dwrapper&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1441153011631&currentQuery=wrapper&currentScope=)

Comment: This configuration element is specific to Experience Manager which might not be used here at all. The same applies to the referenced documentation section...